# php array variable display GPIO wiringpi not showing

Tags: php

I am trying to display the pin status of RaspberryPi GPIO pins using the following script. But it must be wrong as all i get is 000, 000. i can't work out how the array part works on this script.

```
<?php
    $x = array (0,0,0); // set array for number of LEDs
    system ("gpio mode 0 out");
    system ("gpio mode 12 out");    
    system ("gpio mode 13 out");//set GPIO pis as output
    system ("gpio write 0 1");
    system ("gpio write 12 1");
    system ("gpio write 13 1"); // turn on LED
    exec ("gpio read 0", $x); 
    exec ("gpio read 12", $x);  
    exec ("gpio read 13", $x);  // read status of LED and place in array
    echo ($x [0]);  
    echo ($x [1]);
    echo ($x [2]);// print out pin status
    echo "<br>";        
    sleep (2);
    system ("gpio write 0 0");
    system ("gpio write 12 0");
    system ("gpio write 13 0");// turn LED off
    exec ("gpio read 0", $x);
    exec ("gpio read 12", $x);
    exec ("gpio read 13", $x);// Read pins
    echo ($x [0]);// Print out pin status
    echo ($x [1]);
    echo ($x [2]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the script the the one below which is reading the GPIO pins i think

```html
<?php
 $status = 0;
 system ("gpio mode 0 out");
 system ("gpio mode 12 out");
 system ("gpio write 0 1");
 system ("gpio write 12 1");
 exec ("gpio read 0", $status ); 
 exec ("gpio read 12", $status );
 print_r ($status);
 echo ("<br>");
 sleep (2);
 system ("gpio write 0 0");
 exec ("gpio read 0", $status);
 echo ("<br>");
 print_r ($status);
 
?>
```

but the out put on the webpage is

```html
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 )
```

But i cant see why [2] => 0  was added on and the last line is showing all the arrays are still 1 but the LED's are off.